# How to get VSCode intellisense working for Javascript and Nodist on Windows?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense, nodist

I was suprised to find today that after following the directions for [create-react-app in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial) that intellisense isnot working as depicted in the article. I've followed similar instructions on a different machine and it worked and the only obvious differences I can spot at a glance is that the machine that was working was running Windows 7 and may have not been using [Nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist) to manage npm and Node versions.

How can I troubleshoot the intellisense issue? Is there something I've obviously missing from the details I've provided which would prevent intellisense from working as described in the tutorial?

#### VS Code Info:

```
Version 1.20.0
Commit c63189deaa8e620f650cc28792b8f5f3363f2c5b
Date 2018-02-07T17:10:31.920Z
Shell 1.7.9
Renderer 58.0.3029.110
Node 7.9.0
Architecture ia32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I've solved my problem. Although I wasn't seeing the same error that was mentioned int the VSCode documentation it turns out that my problem may have been that it was having trouble locating my version of npm.

By following the [directions](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist#make-it-work-in-your-ide) to find my path to Node that is installed with Nodist and following additional instructions for VSCode to [set the typescript.npm config setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_fixing-npm-not-installed-warning-for-automatic-type-acquisition) to this path then things lit up again for me.

References:

- https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist#make-it-work-in-your-ide
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_fixing-npm-not-installed-warning-for-automatic-type-acquisition